# Edit where a pointer points within a function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, struct

I have a pointer to a struct object in C++.

```
 node *d=head;
```

I want to pass that pointer into a function by reference and edit where it points. I can pass it but it doesn't change where the initial pointer points but only the local pointer in the function. The arguments of the function must be a pointer right? And after how do I change it to show to a different object of the same struct?

Comment: You want to pass `d` to another function but have `head` change when that other function modifies `d` (via a reference)? How did the caller pass you `head`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two basic choices: Pass by *pointer* or pass by *reference*. Passing by pointer requires using a pointer to a pointer:

```
void modify_pointer(node **p) {
    *p = new_value;
}

modify_pointer(&d);
```

Passing by reference uses `&`:

```
void modify_pointer(node *&p) {
    p = new_value;
}

modify_pointer(d);
```

If you pass the pointer as just `node *d`, then modifying `d` within the function will only modify the local copy, as you observed.

Answer (score 3):

Pass it by reference:

```
void foo(node*& headptr)
{
     // change it
     headptr = new node("bla");
     // beware of memory leaks :)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a `node **` as an argument to your function:

```
// f1 :
node *d = head;

f2(&d);

// f2:
void f2(node **victim) {
    //assign to "*victim"
}
```